# non-linear neural network regression - quadratic function is not being estimated correctly

Tags: neural-network, keras, non-linear-regression, nonlinear-functions

I have mostly used ANNs for classification and only recently started to try them out for modeling continuous variables. As an exercise I generated a simple set of (x, y) pairs where y = x^2 and tried to train an ANN to learn this quadratic function.

**The ANN model:**

This ANN has 1 input node (ie. x), 2 hidden layers each with 2 nodes in each layer, and 1 output node. All four hidden nodes use the non-linear tanh activation function and the output node has no activation function (since it is regression).

**The Data:**

For the training set I randomly generated 100 numbers between (-20, 20) for x and computed y=x^2. For the testing set I randomly generated 100 numbers between (-30, 30) for x and also computed y=x^2. I then transformed all x so that they are centered around 0 and their min and max are approximately around -1.5 and 1.5. I also transformed all y similarly but made their min and max about -0.9 and 0.9. This way, all the data falls within that mid range of the tanh activation function and not way out at the extremes.

**The Problem:**

After training the ANN in Keras, I am seeing that only the right half of the polynomial function is being learned, and the left half is completely flat. Does anyone have any ideas why this may be happening? I tried playing around with different scaling options, as well as hidden layer specifications but no luck on that left side.

Thanks!

Attached is the code I used for everything and the image shows the plot of the scaled training x vs the predicted y. As you can see, only half of the parabola is recovered.

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

seed = 10
n = 100
X_train = np.random.uniform(-20, 20, n)
Y_train = X_train ** 2
X_test = np.random.uniform(-30, 30, n)
Y_test = X_test ** 2

#### Scale the data

x_cap = max(abs(np.array(list(X_train) + list(X_test))))
y_cap = max(abs(np.array(list(Y_train) + list(Y_test))))
x_mean = np.mean(np.array(list(X_train) + list(X_test)))
y_mean = np.mean(np.array(list(Y_train) + list(Y_test)))

X_train2 = (X_train-x_mean) / x_cap
X_test2 = (X_test-x_mean) / x_cap
Y_train2 = (Y_train-y_mean) / y_cap
Y_test2 = (Y_test-y_mean) / y_cap

X_train2 = X_train2 * (1.5 / max(X_train2))
Y_train2 = Y_train2 * (0.9 / max(Y_train2))

# define base model
def baseline_model1():
# create model
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Dense(2, input_dim=1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='tanh'))
model1.add(Dense(2, input_dim=1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='tanh'))
model1.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
# Compile model
model1.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
return model1

np.random.seed(seed)
estimator1 = KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model1, epochs=100, batch_size=5, verbose=0)

estimator1.fit(X_train2, Y_train2)
prediction = estimator1.predict(X_train2)
plt.scatter(X_train2, prediction)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UabMe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also consider adding more width to you hidden layer. I changed from 2 to 5 and got a very good fit. I also used more epochs as suggested from rvinas

Answer (score 0):

Your network is very sensible to the initial parameters. The following will help:

- Change your `kernel_initializer` to `glorot_uniform`. Your network is very small and `glorot_uniform` will work better in consonance with the tanh activations. [Glorot uniform](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/initializers.py#L338) will encourage your weights to be initially within a more reasonable range (since it takes into account the fan-in and fan-out of each layer).
- Train your model for more epochs (i.e. 1000).